# print out lines if first three columns match the first three columns in another file

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I have file1 which has 3 columns and file2 which has 8 columns. What I wanted to do was if the first 3 columns in file 2 were found in file 1, then print out the entire 8 columns in file 2.

I have tried codes like

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2$3]++;next};c[$1$2$3]>0' file1 file2
```

...but it only printed out the last matching line in file2.

I have no idea what was wrong. Could anyone help me out? I'd really appreciate it! Thank you in advance!

file1 looks like this

```
7000000185249020    89812   89911
7000000185249020    89912   90011
7000000185249020    202532  202631
7000000185249020    202632  202704
7000000185249020    202764  202863
.....
```

file2 looks like this

```
7000000185249020    89812   89911   100 14.1    20  0.511   48
7000000185249020    89912   90011   100 12.7    19.8    0.642   49
7000000185249020    90012   90023   12  11  17.9    0.704   58.3
```

Comment: Are the two files the same length in lines?  If so you could use `paste` to merge them and then check for `$1==$5 && $2 == $6 [etc]`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti the two files are not same length in lines. file 2 actually has more lines than file 1

Comment: In that case, if either file is longer than the other, all of the nonmatching lines at the end will be thrown out.

Comment: I would like to keep all the matching lines. I don't why the command I used printed out only the last matching line but not the others..

Comment: I believe because `next` skips the rest of the `awk` script for the purposes of the current record.

Comment: Hi @DopeGhoti yes, you are right. But after I excluded 'next' in the command line, it printed out the previous records with first three columns, and only the last matching line had the entire 8 columns. I'm a newbie to linux and awk, do you have any idea how should I fix it? Thank you so much for your kind help!

Comment: Your posted files and command work as expected for me: it outputs the first two lines from file2 and not the third. I suggest you check and make sure there is not something invisible like CRLF instead of LF in file1, or BOM in either file. `cat -v` is good for this, or `sed -n l` (letter ell).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I had ^M at the end of each line in file 1. Problem fixed! Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

If the two files are the same length, you can do this:

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '$1==$4 && $2==$5 && $3==$6 { print $4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}'
```